# How can I use Softdeletes in the models of Employee and User?

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

Employee Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 60);
        $table->string('phone_whats', 30)->nullable();
        $table->string('phone_home', 30)->nullable();
        $table->string('email', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('dt_birthday', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('zipcode', 20)->nullable();
        $table->integer('id_city')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_state')->unsigned();
        $table->string('address', 255)->comment('Endereço')->nullable();
        $table->string('number', 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('rg', 25)->nullable();
        $table->string('cpf', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('password', 255)->nullable();
        $table->foreign('id_city')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->foreign('id_state')->references('id')->on('states');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}    
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('employees');
}
```

User Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->string('name',255);
        $table->integer('id_employee')->unsigned();
        $table->string('email',255)->unique();
        $table->string('password',255);
        $table->foreign('id_employee')->references('id')->on('employees');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

My Model Employee

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'deleted_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone_home', 'phone_whats','email', 'dt_birthday', 'number', 'rg', 'cpf', 'address',
        'id_state', 'id_city', 'password'
    ];
}
```

My Model User

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Employee Controller

```
public function destroy(Employee $employee)
{
        $employee->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

I would like to use softdeletes in the registration of employees and users, when I tested only in the Employee Controller register, my database registration was deleted, I just wanted to apply softdeletes in the employee and the user in the same function, keeping the registration in the database and just fill in the delete_at columns of the two databases leaving them inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it should work - have you runned migrations (if you have added `softDeletes` later)? How do you know your record was deleted? Have you checked it directly in database, or via *Eloquent*? As `SoftDeletes` trait implictly adds to every query clause, returning only models which are not deleted softly, so via `User::find()` you wouldn't get model that was deleted softly.